# In a subquery, how to get data information that came from the with method

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have several tables that do relationship. I'm using the `with()` method to do this. The problem is that there is a table that I need to filter by two pieces of data. One of them I can, because I already have it before the query and the other data is from a table that is in this query.
I can't get this column and compare.

Example of what I'm trying to do.

```php
$groups = GroupProduct::where('status', 1);
$groups = $groups->with(['groupProductProduct.product' => function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('products.situation', 1)
        ->with(['items.orderitems' => function($query2) use ($id) {
            $query2->where([
                    ['order_items.order_id', $id],
                    ['order_items.group_product_id', 'group_products.id']
                ])
                ->with('subitems');
        }]);
}]);
$groups = $groups->get();
```

or

```php
$groups = GroupProduct::where('status', 1);
$groups = $groups->with(['groupProductProduct.product' => function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('products.situation', 1)
        ->with(['items.orderitems' => function($query2) use ($id) {
            $query2->where([
                    ['order_items.order_id', $id],
                    ['order_items.group_product_id', 'group_products_products.group_product_idd']
                ])
                ->with('subitems');
        }]);
}]);
$groups = $groups->get();
```

It's this where I can't pass, the second one doesn't work.

```php
$query2->where([
    ['order_items.order_id', $id],
    ['order_items.group_product_id', 'group_products.id']
]);
```

Comment: 1) when comparing columns, you should use `whereColumn`. `whereColumn('order_items.group_product_id', 'group_products.id')`. **THAT SAID, I do not think it's going to work**.

Comment: You are dealing with relationships, not SQL joins. `'group_products_products.group_product_id` is probably not even **available** in that query.

Comment: Check the SQL output of the relationship query by dumping it. `...->with(['items.orderitems' => function($query2) { $query2->...->dd(); })`

Comment: Do you have any solution ideas? I just can't get any results.

Comment: None without knowing the structure of the tables/models in question